# How do I conditionally update List<Object> items using LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

How do I conditionally update `List<object>` items using LINQ, I have managed to get a way to update all items in `List<object>` using this syntax:

```
var updatedList = sourceList.Select( x => { x.PropertyA = NewValue; return x; }).ToList();
```

Comment: Use `Where`. Also, linq isn't designed to handle side-effects.

Comment: Good day, using Where Clause will return a few items that match the condition, I wanted to conditionally update the items and return unfiltered list.

Comment: What's the point, you're mutating the original list and returning a shallow copy of it. Could as well do `foreach (var item in sourceList) { item.PropA = newValue; }`

Comment: Don't do this. It's an abuse of LINQ and you gain nothing over a simple foreach loop, and in fact, you lose readability. See this article: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/

Answer (score 0):

var updatedList = sourceList.Select( x => {return x = x.PropertyA == SomeValue ? x1 : x;}).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

You can either project it to a new collection using the .Select, or affect the original list using the .ForEach extension method. Both are shown below, given an arbitrary condition.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<testClass> ogList = new List<testClass>();

        bool testCondition = true;

        //use the select to update and project to new collection
        var updated =
            ogList 
            .Select(x =>
            {
                if (testCondition)
                    x.testProp = 1;

                return x;
            }).ToList();
        //use the foreach to update original collection
        ogList.ForEach(x =>
        {
            if (testCondition)
                x.testProp = 1;
        });
    }
}

public class testClass
{
    public int testProp { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the lessons shared in this post, I greatly appreciate your time and effort to concoct this solution. May I also know what are the disadvantages of the technique I used?

Comment: Many people discourage the use of linq to update objects in a collection, but it is largely a matter of style and preference. Performance should be considered and characterized on a case by case basis and is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
sourceList.Where(w => w.CheckProperty == valueofProperty).Select(s => {
                            s.PropertyA  = valueofPropertyA ;
                            s.PropertyB  = valueofPropertyB;
                            return s;
                        }).ToList();
```

Comment: As mentioned in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49957491/how-do-i-conditionally-update-listobject-items-using-linq#comment86931049_49957491), LINQ isn't really designed to introduce side effects like the code in your answer does.

Comment: @WaiHaLee this code is running and its update object when the condition is satisfied

Comment: I didn't say that the code won't run - but it is unusual to use LINQ like this. As [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49958675/1364007) shows, you can use a foreach loop to modify the list - which is more normal.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this answer will help you.
So here I creating objects of my database, list of my db_table and table.

```
private DB dbs = new DB();
List<tab1> lst = new List<tab1>();
tab1 tabobj = new tab1();
```

here you will get the list of data in your table

`````````````
lst = dbs.tab1.ToList();
````````````
updating the table 
```````````
tabobj.c1 = "value";
tabobj.c2 = "value";
`````````````

adding updated columns to table

```
dbs.tab1.Add(tabobj);
```

save changes here

```
dbs.SaveChanges();
```

data of updated table

```
lst = dbs.tab1.ToList();
```